# How can I create a root folder for my projects in Eclipse as recommended by EGit?

Tags: eclipse, egit

[EGit User Guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_a_Git_Repository_for_multiple_Projects) suggests making a Repository working directory to store your projects, so you can add multiple projects to one repository:

[image]

How do I do this? I tried Eclipse's Create New Folder -- it only creates subfolders for projects. I tried moving the projects into a directory I created and hitting refresh -- nothing happened, and when I closed Eclipse it lost track of the .project file. I tried creating a new working set, but it didn't seem like the same thing.

Is this even a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this:

1. Create a directory somewhere (e.g. `~/git/myrepo`)
2. In the console/terminal: enter the directory you just created
3. Create the Git repository using `git init`
4. In Eclipse, right click on your project and select *Team -> Share Project...*
5. As repository, select `~/git/myrepo/.git`
6. Working directory is `~/git/myrepo`
7. Click `Finish`

You can also try and create the repository using the "Share" dialog as well. This is something I did not try.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this screenshot comes from the Git Repositories View, not Package Explorer. So you can achieve this simply by creating your repository in a folder outside of your Eclipse workspace.